# Missing values in Categorical Variables in CatBoost (python)

Tags: python, dataframe, null, categorical-data, catboost

CatBoost can encode categorical variables which is great. However, when categorical features contain missing values in the form np.nan, they can't be processed. This is stated in CatBoost documentation here:
[cb missing values](https://catboost.ai/en/docs/concepts/algorithm-missing-values-processing)

However, I read in this GitHub thread that CatBoost can in fact handle categorical variables with missing values.
[github thread](https://github.com/catboost/catboost/issues/1245)

I tried a mini example to test it:

```py
from catboost import CatBoostClassifier
# Initialize data
cat_features = [0, 1]
train_data = [["a", np.nan, 1, 4, 5, 6],
              ["a", "b", 4, 5, 6, 7],
              ["c", "d", 30, 40, 50, 60]]
train_labels = [1, 1, -1]
eval_data = [["a", "b", 2, 4, 6, 8],
             ["a", "d", 1, 4, 50, 60]]

# Initialize CatBoostClassifier
model = CatBoostClassifier(iterations=2,
                           learning_rate=1,
                           depth=2)
# Fit model
model.fit(train_data, train_labels, cat_features)
```

Here we get the error, because column `0`has null:

```
CatBoostError: Invalid type for cat_feature[non-default value idx=0,feature_idx=1]=nan : cat_features must be integer or string, real number values and NaN values should be converted to string.
```

How can I make this code work without manually filling the null value?

Comment: I think your little experiment and the docu provides enough evidence to prove that comment in the github thread wrong.. I cant see an error in your experiment

Answer (score 1):

It actually all works fine if you use Catboost's recommended Pool method that maps the data.

```
train_data = Pool(data=[[1, np.nan, 5, 6],
                        [4, 5, 6, 7],
                        [30, 40, 50, 60]],
                  label=[1, 1, -1],
                  weight=[0.1, 0.2, 0.3])

model = CatBoostClassifier(iterations=10)

model.fit(train_data)

Learning rate set to 0.058839
0:  learn: 0.6879920    total: 2.32ms   remaining: 20.8ms
1:  learn: 0.6815428    total: 2.63ms   remaining: 10.5ms
2:  learn: 0.6765119    total: 2.86ms   remaining: 6.67ms
3:  learn: 0.6715373    total: 3.86ms   remaining: 5.8ms
4:  learn: 0.6653022    total: 4.24ms   remaining: 4.24ms
5:  learn: 0.6591482    total: 5.83ms   remaining: 3.88ms
6:  learn: 0.6543562    total: 6.11ms   remaining: 2.62ms
7:  learn: 0.6496176    total: 6.34ms   remaining: 1.59ms
8:  learn: 0.6436669    total: 6.53ms   remaining: 725us
9:  learn: 0.6377932    total: 6.75ms   remaining: 0us
<catboost.core.CatBoostClassifier at 0x14d60bdd8>
```

Comment: the data in your answer does not contain any categorical variables

Answer (score 0):

conclusion:catboost doesn't provide fuctionality to handle missing values in categorical variables.

original text:
The feature f is categorical and takes the value None for some object Obj.

A matrix is used for the training. The column that contains the value of the feature f for the object Obj contains the value None.

Each categorical feature value is converted to a string during the training to calculate the corresponding hash value. The None value is converted to the string None.

After the training the prediction is performed on file. The column with the feature _f _ contains the value N/A, which would be parsed as None if it was read to a pandas.DataFrame before the training.

The hash value of the string N/A is calculated during the prediction. This value is not equal to the hash value of the string None.

Thus, the model doesn't collate this value with the one in the training dataset, therefore the prediction is incorrect.

Since it is not possible to guarantee that the string representation of floating point and None values are the same when reading data from a file or converting the value to a string in Python or any other language, it is required to use strings instead of floating point and None values.

see FAQ url:[catboost FAQ](https://catboost.ai/en/docs/concepts/faq)